# Why after run "python runcanvas.py" command?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu-18.04

Why do I get this error after executing this command?

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):<br>
File &quot;runcanvas.py&quot;, line 51, in &lt;module&gt;<br>
From internal.debug import debug_enabled<br>
ImportError: no module named internal.debug
```

I tried with Python2 and Python3, but not working.

[image: click to error screenshot]

Comment: You don't have a module named internal.debug. From where did you get this piece of code?

Comment: Related to the immunity canvas tool.